# _i64toa_ function and equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c++

can someone explain me what does `_i64toa_s` function does in **c++** ?
and what is the equivalent in **Java**?

I didn't find any documentation on this function.

Comment: "I didn't find any documentation on this function." Fix your google.

Comment: whatever I read was not clear to me.

Comment: I bet it turns a 64 bit value into an array of bytes.

Comment: *whatever I read was not clear to me* Then [edit] your question to tell us exactly what you find unclear.

Comment: Long.toString(x)

Comment: Not a C++ function but a Microsoft one. (which you can call from C++)

Answer (score 0):

It converts a 64-bit integer into a string. The java equivalent is `Long.toString(value)`.

Oh, and there is some documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h.aspx